# MSMQ::GetPrivateQueuesByMachine fails when using "localhost"

Tags: c#, msmq

I have software running locally and on a number of servers that does the following:

```
var queues = MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine("localhost");
```

One server in particular throws an exception:

```
System.Messaging.MessageQueueException: Message Queue service is not available.
  at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine(String machineName)
```

MSMQ is installed the same as it is on my other machines.  I also have multiple WCF Services successfully bound to `net.msmq://localhost/private/...`.

**Is there some reason that MSMQ might not be bound to localhost?**

After checking out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.getprivatequeuesbymachine.aspx), it seems that I should be using ".", which works great, but I'd rather avoid changing code and redeploying, when localhost seems to be totally efficient.  FWIW, here are the results of some other tests I ran:

```
var queues = MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine("."); // succeeds
var queues = MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine("localhost"); // fails
var queues = MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine("127.0.0.1"); // fails
var queues = MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine("machineName"); // fails
```

Comment: Did you got any solution fro this issue?If so will you help me

Comment: @Arun I did not.  I just started using "." everywhere.  For shame... =[

Comment: Ok thanks for the replay...I think I need to find anyother way..

Answer (score 1):

There is likely to be a HOSTS file entry mapping localhosts IP address to some machine name.

Comment: Meant to mention checking that in the question.  localhost is indeed listed and works from a web browser.  Additionally, considering that 127.0.0.1 fails, it sort of trumps the hosts file.

Comment: True. In your test, you have "." succeeding but "machinename" not. I assume machineName is just you hiding the real machine name.
"." should resolve to the local machine name and then connect. Therefore there seems something wrong with the way the machine resolves it's own name.